# Protected Tags Error

Tags: functions, function-construction, warning-messages

While trying to run this piece of code:

```
Spacings[e_, f_, dim_] := Sort[Rest[Eigen2[e,f,dim]] - Drop[Eigen2[e,f,dim], -1]]//N;
SpacingsG[e_, f_, dim_] := ColumnForm[Spacings[e, f, dim]];
```

I get the following error:

```
SetDelayed::write : Tag Spacings in Spacing[e_,f_,dim_] is Protected. >>
```

Does anyone know how to go around this error? (and for which reason am I getting this message). I'm fairly new to Mathematica.

Comment: `Spacings` is built-in and `Protected`. Consider a different name, or using lower-case (`spacings[]`).

Comment: This is a rather basic mistake but rather than close it I chose to mark it as a duplicate of a slightly more involved question with the hope that this is more helpful.